# How to run a whole Java file added as a snippet in JShell?

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

I tried installing JDK 9 Early access version 172 to play around with JShell. 
When I tried to open a simple java file and execute it after adding it as a snippet, it just showed modified class Test and increased the snippet number. Can you please help me realize where I went wrong?

```
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 9-ea
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> /open G:\kavitha\Test.java

jshell> /list

   1 : public class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args){
                 int i = 1;
                 int j = 2;
             System.out.println("Sum of 1 and 2 is : " + (i+j));
        }
       }

jshell> /1
public class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args){
                 int i = 1;
                 int j = 2;
             System.out.println("Sum of 1 and 2 is : " + (i+j));
        }
}
|  modified class Test

jshell> /list

   2 : public class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args){
                 int i = 1;
                 int j = 2;
             System.out.println("Sum of 1 and 2 is : " + (i+j));
        }
       }
```

Comment: Hi, could you edit your question and replace the image with the actual text, formatted as code to be readable? This way your question will be more usable, searchable, etc. [See this for details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Sure. I will do that. Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: jshell is good in theory but their implementation is a true disappointment. It should catch errors like `int i=1; String i="redeclare error";` but it doesn't.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`/open` only loads the file, after that you have to tell jshell what you want to execute.

Example:

```
jshell> /open Test.java

jshell> /list

   1 : class Test {
           public static void main(String[] args) {
               System.out.println("Hello Kavitha");
           }
           int rollDice() {
               return 1 + (int)(6 * Math.random());
           }
       }

jshell> Test.main(new String[0])
Hello Kavitha

jshell> new Test().rollDice()
$3 ==> 3
```

Here I have executed `main` method, but I can also use the loaded class as I want, create a new instance, invoke a method, etc.

Shortcut `/<id>` re-runs snippet with that id. In your case, snippet 1 only loads the class and executes nothing, so by executing `/1` you re-loaded the same class, again without executing it.

After running my example above, `/2` would re-run the main method, and `/3` would re-roll the dice:

```
jshell> /3
new Test().rollDice()
$4 ==> 1

jshell> /3
new Test().rollDice()
$5 ==> 6

jshell> /3
new Test().rollDice()
$6 ==> 2
```

---

### Addendum: `/open` & compilation, class loading, class initialization

(Trying to clarify *why* `/open` did not execute the main method of your class, and to show that it makes sense)

When you `/open` a file, JShell will add the content of the file *as if you typed it into the shell*.

It will then *compile* the snippet(s), but it will not [*initialize*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17693926/6730571) classes if there were any.

(I'm not sure whether or not if will *load* classes, which is the step before initialization, it's difficult to tell, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44236197/6730571) that was an attempt to explore the internals of JShell, it shows how class names in JShell are translated for the user, and failed attempts to see the list of loaded classes -- but that matters less than compilation & initialization)

If I open `SnippetWithError.txt` which contains the following:

```
System.out.println("Hey")
class Foo { int n=33; } bar
```

(yes it does not need to be a java file, it's really a bunch of text you include in the shell for evaluation)

```
jshell> /open SnippetWithError.txt
Hey
|  Error:
|  cannot find symbol
|    symbol:   variable bar
|   bar
|   ^-^
```

See it printed "Hey", and it has included class `Foo`:

```
jshell> new Foo().n
$2 ==> 33
```

So, JShell *compiles* when you `/open`, it executes the statements, but if some statements are class or method declarations, it does not execute those, it does not even *initialize* the classes.

See below how the imports are counted as separate statements in the history, then the class declaration is in its own statement (#3):

```
jshell> /open HasStaticInitBlock.java

jshell> /list

1 : import java.time.Duration;
2 : import java.time.Instant;
3 : class HasStaticInitBlock {
        static Instant t0 = Instant.now();
        static {
            System.out.println("Class initialized at " + t0);
        }
        static Duration timeSinceInit() {
            return Duration.between(t0, Instant.now());
        }
    }

jshell> HasStaticInitBlock.timeSinceInit()
Class initialized at 2017-06-07T06:49:06.746185Z
$4 ==> PT0.040414S

jshell> HasStaticInitBlock.timeSinceInit()
$5 ==> PT2.343019S
```

Class initialization was only performed when needed.